# Gradient of a vector function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a vectorial function $f$, defined on the set of all $n$-dimensional vectors.
$f(x) = \log(x^TAx)$, where $\log$ is the natural logarithm, $x^T$ is $x$ transpose and $A$ is a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix.

I have to calculate the gradient and then the Hessian of this function.

I know how to  compute the gradient and Hessian of a vectorial function when it is defined with respect to its components and I know the definition of the gradient.

But I don't know how to approach computing the gradient for this function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT

I know the answer is $\nabla f(x) = \frac{2Ax}{x^TAx}$

UPDATE

I succeeded in computing the gradient of $f$ and now I am looking for the Hessian:)

Comment: I think that $x\neq 0$ and $A>0$ is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$    f_i= \frac{d}{dt} f(x+te_i) $$ 
$$=\frac{d}{dt} \log ( (x+te_i)^T A(x+te_i) ) = \frac{1}{e^f} (e_i^T Ax +x^T Ae_i) $$

$$ = \frac{2e_i^TAx}{e^f}\Rightarrow {\rm grad} \ f=\frac{2}{e^f} Ax $$

$$ f_{ij} = \frac{d}{dt} f_i(x+te_j) =\frac{d}{dt} \frac{2e_i^TA(x+te_j) }{e^{f(x+te_j) }}  =\frac{2e_i^TAe_j }{e^f} + \frac{2e_i^TAx }{e^f} (-1) \frac{2e_j^TAx }{e^f}       $$ $$=
\frac{2A_{ij}}{e^f} + \frac{-4(e_i^TAx)(e_j^TAx )}{e^{2f}} $$

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain very well, but this doesn't look like what I'm expecting to see.

Comment: In the end, I ended up with grad f = (2*A*x)/($x^T$*A*x)

Comment: I see. I will correct it